# Boot from an HDD where Ubuntu Server 14.04 is installed

Tags: boot

I have in my hands an 1.5 TB HDD that supposedly stores a clone of an remote VPS with Ubuntu Server installed.

I have connected the HDD to the motherboard, and it looks the HDD is detected correctly.

[image]

When I try to boot my PC just connecting this 1.5 TB HDD, it says something like "No bootable device found".

To know if the HDD is bootable or not, I searched on Google and found this:

https://superuser.com/questions/329467/how-to-see-if-usb-stick-has-mbr

So I have run:

`file -s /dev/sda`

and I get:

`/dev/sda: x86 boot sector`

Comment: Your MBR does not contain a boot-loader.

Comment: @mook765 thanks, so in that way I can not boot my PC using that HDD, right? In that case, is it possible to do something to boot from it?

Comment: That's correct, without a boot-loader in the MBR you can't boot this drive. It should be possible to install a boot-loader, but I don't know how this would have to be done in your configuration.